# How to create stacked chart together with column chart in Tableau?

Tags: charts, bar-chart, tableau-api, stacked-chart, column-chart

I have to show two graphs stacked chart with "open" and "new" (value) categories and combine it with normal bar chart for category "closed". First I tried to do it from one data set, then I have decided to create a separate data set for "closed" (Closed value) category.

But I get in the best case I get separate the staked chart for value (it has to be stacked diagram where values for "open" and "new" are colored) and separate bar chart for "closed" and I don't know how to put them on the one chart.

[image]

I need those two charts to be together like:

[image]

I created the separate data for "closed" category: [Data Closed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/masxmncz958nklg/PythonExport%20-%20CopyClosed.xlsx?dl=0)
and data with all formation ("open", "new", closed"). Usually I filter "closed" data out when I take this data together with "closed" data. Data:[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pacffpnfk92h2s2/PythonExport%20-%20Copy.xlsx?dl=0)

How to create stacked chart together with column chart in Tableau?

[image]

Still I could not manage to bring closed data as separate column. There is a problem with type variable, Type (Sheet 2) consists only out of "closed" category but Type in Sheet 1 out of all three. Thank you @Jose Cherian What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You already have the data, it is just colored incorrectly. please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using data blending and shared axis or dual axis charts. Link the closed value data source by Time period and Type. Then drop the dimensions and measures as below.
[image]

**EDIT:**
You need to use separate color for each chart. For 'sum of Value', drop type under color. For 'sum of  closed value', dont drop anything under color.(Just use a solid color as you only have one item)